# Get the count of messages on condition in AWS cloud watch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Am trying to get the number of filtered messages in Cloud watch using the insight query like below

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| filter @message like /Message studentInfo processed in/
| parse 'Message studentInfo processed in * seconds.' as c_time
| stats count(c_time) as total_count, count(c_time>5.0) as filtered_count
```

am getting both count as same. How can we get the count having value > 5?

Comment: Do you need both counts?

Comment: Can't you try c_time>5.0 in the filter?